# SwiftUI: how to detect when List is scrolled?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swift-keyboard

I have a view with a search bar at the top and a SwiftUI `List` below. I need to detect when the `List` is scrolled so I can dismiss the search bar keyboard. How would I call some code when the `List` is scrolled? Thanks!

Comment: Add a drag gesture.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I recommend to use `simultaneousGesture` modifier as in below:

```
List {
  // ... your list items
}
.simultaneousGesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ _ in
    // if keyboard is opened then hide it
}))
```

*Update: [verified](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestDetectListBeginToScroll.swift) with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4 - for the use-case formulated by PO still works fine.*

Comment: Anyone have an explanation of what's going on here. i.e. why this works

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: The `onChanged` closure is called only once. What is the reason for this?

Comment: This solution prevents any swipeActions from working smoothly