# Detecting Scroll on Carousel List on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swiftui, carousel, apple-watch, swiftui-list

Trying to see whether there is a way that item scroll can be detected on a ListView with CarouselListStyling (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/carouselliststyle).

I am looking for an effect similar to Apple's calendar app, where when you scroll through your events, text in the header changes (The day and date changes when your events start on a different day).

[image]

Example of the code I have is:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
    Text("Text I want to update")
    
    List {
        ForEach(events, id: \.self) { event in
            EventCard(event: event)
        }
    }
    .listStyle(.carousel)
    
}
```

And I would like the text to be some State variable that will be updated when the list is scrolled.

In a perfect would there would just be a closure I could tap into something like:

```
@State var text: String = "hello"
....
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
    Text(text)
    
    List {
        ForEach(events, id: \.self) { event in
            EventCard(event: event)
        }
    }
    .listStyle(.carousel)
    .onScroll { viewedRow in
        self.text = textForViewedRow(viewedRow)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any sample code for your app?

Comment: I have added some sample code. I am just using a standard SwiftUI list in a VStack, basically all I need is a way to update the text when the carousel is scrolled.

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59620519/swiftui-how-to-detect-when-list-is-scrolled

Comment: Partially, but Apple Watch can also be scrolled via the crown which this answer won't cover I believe and it doesn't allow me to detect what is the front item in the carousel.